# Laravel 5: Getting values from DB to config/services.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just added Facebook and Google login to my website, and the values for the client_id and client_secret are set from the Admin Control Panel and stored in my database's settings table.

When I'm trying to do something like this (on config/services.php):

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => Setting::findOrFail('facebook_client_id')->first()->value,
    'client_secret' => '',
    'redirect' => env('APP_URL') . '/login/facebook/callback',
],

'google' => [
    'client_id' => '',
    'client_secret' => '',
    'redirect' => env('APP_URL') . '/login/google/callback',
],
```

I get a blank page.

Of course I added this on top of my config/services.php file:

```
use App\Setting;
```

Comment: I would suggest you not to access db values from config. Things like facebook client id doesn't change daily but changes with environment. So the best place for these values are .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add `use App\Setting` to the top of the file, because it's not a class.

Just use `App\Setting::` directly in the code.

Comment: Well, I've helped you with code, now it's correct code. Now you need to debug the error. Make sure `App\Setting::findOrFail('facebook_client_id')->first()->value,` works. Run it somewhere else, in `tinker`, for example. Also, look into Laravel `error.log` file etc. I can't help you if I don't know what's happening on your side. ;)

Comment: Because no error shows up, the log file doesn't update... As I said all I get is a blank page. And I checked in tinker, it does work there.

Comment: Turn on DEBUG mode then, install debug bar, check web server errors.